# How to optimize: add/subtract a value until it is within a predefined range?

Tags: objective-c, math

I have a value range, say the iPhone screen size 480x320. I have a position that may be outside the range, let's say the position's x coordinate is 600 for example.

In order to adjust the x coordinate to its on-screen position I can do: 600 - 480 = 120

But when the value is greater than two times 480 I'd have to run a loop, subtract 480 until the resulting number is below 480.

I know there's an optimization to this problem revolving around division/modulo but I just can't find a good answer (or question) related to this. Mainly because I can only guess possibly helpful search phrases.

I'm feeling sick today and for the live of me I can't wrap my head around it. I'd welcome any pointers, even a "close as duplicate".

PS: this is for Objective-C but any language will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). The solution for the case of a width of `480` is:

```
x % 480
```

Modulo will guarantee that the resulting value is between 0 and 479.

Comment: pshhhh … I knew it wasn't hard, but that I had no idea I was *that* sick. Thanks! Signing off, I need a rest. :o